# How to speed up the foreach loop execution in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

My linq query executes quite fast but it brings out around 10K results, so its foreach loop takes a bit long time, is there a way by which I can execute the same in lesser time?

Comment: Run it on a faster computer?

Comment: A little bit code would be better

Comment: It might be possible to run the loop in parallel.

Comment: If it's possible for the collection you have, try to split it up and run loops on seperate parts by using threads.  
This works as long as the entries in your collection have no link with each other, which might change the outcome of your operation.

Comment: I really don't get what was the need for the code here as it was a basic question. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you're performing the operation on every record returned, there's no way to shortcut that.

Your only option would be to either limit the number of elements further, or improve the efficiency of the operation being performed inside of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: or using [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) instead of LINQ.

Comment: @Nolonar - That's not even close to a guarantee. If the process isn't well suited to parallelization, PLINQ can be quite a bit slower.

Comment: I agree, I think I can use paging and then fetch only limited records.